# generator' object has no attribute 'data', problems loading some file with scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, io, scipy, arff

Im new with python and I'm triying to load .arff file with python this is what i tried:

```
import arff , numpy as np

file1 = open('/Users/user/Desktop/example.arff')
dataset = arff.load(file1)

print dataset

data = np.array(dataset.data)
print data
```

The problem is the following output:

```
    data = np.array(dataset.data)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Why is this happening? and how should i avoid it?. This is the .arff:

```
@relation foo
@attribute width  numeric
@attribute height numeric
@attribute color  {red,green,blue,yellow,black}
@data
5.0,3.25,blue
4.5,3.75,green
3.0,4.00,red
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two arff's that can be installed, you probably need to install [liac-arff](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff), you currently have `arff` installed which returns a generator from `arff.load`.

```
file1 = open('example.arff', "rb")
dataset = arff.load(file1)
print(dataset)
{u'attributes': [(u'width', u'NUMERIC'), (u'height', u'NUMERIC'), (u'color', [u'red', u'green', u'blue', u'yellow', u'black'])], u'relation': u'foo', u'description': u'', u'data': [[5.0, 3.25, u'blue'], [4.5, 3.75, u'green'], [3.0, 4.0, u'red']]}
```

For the arff you have installed don's pass a file object just load the file directly:

```
dataset = arff.load('eg.arff')
for row in dataset:
    x = row.color
    print(x)
blue
green
red
```

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the edit. When this is the output of your code answer: ´<generator object load at 0x102a119b0>´, how can i get this ouput:`{u'attributes': [(u'width', u'NUMERIC'), (u'height', u'NUMERIC'), (u'color', [u'red', u'green', u'blue', u'yellow', u'black'])], u'relation': u'foo', u'description': u'', u'data': [[5.0, 3.25, u'blue'], [4.5, 3.75, u'green'], [3.0, 4.0, u'red']]}`?

Comment: install iac-arff then use the code as in my first example, you need to uninstall the arff you currently have installed  first though

Answer (score 2):

The `pypi` page for `arff` shows how to use its `load`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arff/0.9

```
>>> import arff
>>> for row in arff.load('example.arff'):
...     print(row.hair_color)
...     print(row[-1])
...
>>> print(list(arff.load('example.arff')))
[[Row(hair_color='blonde', age=17.2, patno=1),
 Row(hair_color='blue', age=27.2, patno=2),
 Row(hair_color='blue', age=18.2, patno=3)]
```

Since `arff.load` is a Python `generator`, it does not load the file immediately.  Rather you have to call it 'iteratively', as in the:

```
for row in arff.load(...)
```

wrapping it in `list()` has the same effect - calling the `load` repeatedly until it is done.

Answer (score 1):

As of python 3 it seems like the list(arff.load('...')) method doesn't return attributes with the arff module (0.9) instead use Row._data (private but when it sticks, push):

```
for row in list(arff.load(fid)):
   print( row._data )
```

http://pydoc.net/Python/arff/0.9/arff/