# Switching from Python 2.7 to 3.7 error: "TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am upgrading my Python environment and this code that used to run in Python versions 2.7 and 3.6 now is displaying this error message:

**TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable**

Precisely on this instruction:
np.array(dataset['data'])

where dataset is an variable containing arff file loaded...

Trying to dig I undeerstood that is something about iterator... but with the samples I tried I could not fix... Any help is welcome!

```
dataset = arff.load(open('datasets/temporal_extract_14_3_2.first_1_hours.arff',  'r'))
data = np.array(dataset['data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338678/generator-object-has-no-attribute-data-problems-loading-some-file-with-scipy), it is likely that you installed the wrong library in Python 3.

Comment: Hi Rafael, i used [liac-arff](https://pypi.org/project/liac-arff/)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the open file handler.

```
dataset = arff.load('datasets/temporal_extract_14_3_2.first_1_hours.arff')
```

Comment: If [liac-arff](https://pypi.org/project/liac-arff/) was meant to be used, then a call to `open` is probably needed.

Comment: I do call open function... The error message does not happen in the load... it happens in "np.array(dataset['data'])", which is weird since it runs fine in Python versions 2.7 and 3.6....

Comment: Right.  Because the load creates a generator via the open context.  The issue is coming from the point you treat the generator as a sequence `dataset['data']'` presumes the existence of `data` something that may not exist yet, which is why you are getting the sequence error.  Have you tried it the way I suggested yet?

Comment: `arff.load` claims to return a dictionary, but it calls `decoder`, which says that with an `open` file, it reads lines iteratively, i.e. the generator return.  So while the documentation is confusing, you should try the file name call if you don't want to deal with the generator.

Comment: hpaulj can you provide me an example please?

Comment: hi @eatmeimadanish ! YES, I did try! but no lucky so far take a look on the picture: https://imgur.com/a/v2qwEO8

Comment: d = dataset['data'] gives this error message:
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: try `dataset = dict(dataset)`